# SharePoint 2013 Open Library in Windows Explorer Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, open-with-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

I am getting the following error when attempting to open a document library in explorer view:

> "We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add
>   this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again."

The error seems to be only affecting site collections OTHER than the root site collection. As a workaround I have tried to use an URL like "\yourportal.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\"   but it is sporadic because the WebClient service crashes after two minutes. Other errors you may receive are

> "Cannot find file "\yourportal.com\" Verify the path or Internet
>   address is correct."

[image]

Can anyone give some hint on how to proceed to identify the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within SharePoint Central Admin, the Explicit Managed paths for the defined site collections were missing a root site collection. For example, division/home was missing the /division site collection thus explorer view could not open the path.

Add the additional Explicit inclusion managed path(s) and then add the corresponding root site collection(s).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I think the `Desktop experience feature` is not installed and `Web client` service might be not started so try to follow this

- Open Server Manager –> Manage –> Add Roles and Features.
- Select Features from the left step navigation –> User Interfaces and
  Infrastructure –> Desktop Experience.
- Click Next then Install.
- Restart Server. Go to Services by clicking  Run –> `Services.msc` –>
- Start `WebClient` Service. Go back to your document library it should
  be working.

> Ref: [WE’RE HAVING A PROBLEM OPENING THIS LOCATION IN FILE EXPLORER,
> ADD THIS WEBSITE TO YOUR TRUSTED SITES LIST AND TRY AGAIN](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)

Comment: Works for me [SP2013 - WS2012 - SQLSRV 2012R2].

Comment: +1 this worked for me as I've got the site already added in Trusted sites

Comment: It's done now :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IE, go to Internet Options > Security > Local intranet > click on "sites" > Advanced > add the website to the zone. You may be have to reload IE to take effect.

Comment: Good point, this is very important and should be done first. Group policy can add this also.

Comment: How could it be done by Group Policy?

Comment: Hi @KGahbiche - this was a bit broader answer than a quick reply so I posted this Q&A - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134437/group-policy-add-sharepoint-site-to-local-intranet-or-trusted-site-enable-pa/134438#134438

Comment: I just had this too - a user could not use 'open with explorer'; I checked Security/Local Intranet/Sites/Advanced (same steps as KhalilG), all was fine here (in fact all this is managed by System Administrator).  Yet when the user selected OK and exited the menu we found that 'open with explorer' started working again!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Windows Server 2016 and you want to connect to your SharePoint sites using the Explorer mode, there are big chances to encounter “We’re having a problem opening this location in File Explorer.” warning message.
That’s because the WebClient windows service (responsible for the “translation” into Explorer mode) is by default not installed with the Windows Server 2016 OS. The same story was also on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (and the fix was to activate the “Desktop Experience” feature from the Server Manager console).

This time (in case of Windows Server 2016), in order to get the WebClient windows service you need to activate the “WebDAV Redirector” feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in CA / application management. Highlight the application with the trouble and click managed paths in the ribbon after it becomes active. If the problem is occurring in sub-folders use wildcard instead of explicit. If you are adding a wildcard, you may have to delete if there's already an explicit path defined.

Answer (score 0):

Installing WebDAV Redirctor on 2016 worked like a charm. No more errors and site is opening fine in file exporer.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint in Microsoft 365, open the document library with the file or folders you want to move or copy. Select the View menu and then select View in File Explorer. Note: View in File Explorer works for a modern library in Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer 10 or 11.